# Asio4all: Simultaneous output on two devices possible?

Tags: cubase

I am not sure I understood the point of asio4all correctly. I have two USB Audio interfaces (Yamaha AG06 and Line6 Pod X3) that I am using in Cubase AI 8. I use the POD to record the guitar, and the AG06 as a mixer and for a keyboard.

If I switch on two devices in asio4all and I added the corresponding busses in Cubase , shouldn't the sound be redirected to both ?

How can I use one device for recording and the other one for playing (except switching from one driver to the other) ? If this is not possible with asio4all, what is the point of the ability to turn on more than one device at the same time ?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Unfortunately Asio4All in cubase does not support using more than one device . Whichever device is switched on first gets control of the driver. ASIO officially does not support more device per driver although there are workarounds for other DAWS.

The only exception is FL Studio.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how FL Studio is different? Is it able to somehow use ASIO4All drivers for more than one interface at a time?

Comment: Yes it is. I had it set up that way for a while.https://www.image-line.com/support/FLHelp/html/envsettings_asio4all.htm